# Preferred linux partition sizes on modern systems

Tags: linux, partitioning

How much should I allocate for `/` (root/boot) in 2015? Do I need to account for additional programs to be installed in this partition?

I don’t want this to be a discussion about the size of the swap partition. Any excess will be allocated to home.

I’m on a crappy laptop, and only have about 80GB. Dual booting Windows is taking a good chunk, and I can’t shrink it any further.

**Edit:**
I have 4 GB ram. I'm a GUI user primarily, but going to do some web development. I want to have plenty of software.

What is the benefit of having a separate `/boot` partition as opposed to just `/`?

Comment: Are there 4 or 3 partitions? `/`, `boot`, `/home`, `<swap>`?

Comment: Which distro and desktop?  How loaded of a software bundle?  How much software do you expect to load?  Are you a GUI user or a command line user?

Comment: The advice I've seen is 3 partitions: /(root/boot), /home, and swap.  Swap = RAM (4 GB in your case).  /(root) size depends on whether you go with a lightweight Linux or something like KDE and a mountain of full-featured software.  For a lightweight with lightweight software, 5 GB would probably do it.  KDE with everything but the kitchen sink in full-featured software, probably 10 to 15 GB.  /home: as much as you need after that.  I used KDE as an example because it's probably the largest desktop/bundle.

Answer (score 1):

My standard start layout for any server is a lvm based configuration with:

```
/        5 GB 
/boot  256 MB 
/var     2 GB
```

this is my starting point, and then I add space or partitions whenever.

If you are planning to use graphical interface, make `/` 10 GB to start with.

Comment: I looked into what `/var` was. I decided to go with 256MB /boot, 2GB /var, 6GB swap, 50GB /boot, 25GB (free space), 150GB /home

Comment: be careful with a standalone /boot partition on distros like Ubuntu, by default, when you upgrade, the new kernels will fill the space until full.